# Split python code with classes refering to each other into multiple files without circular import error

Tags: python, file, class, split, module

I would like to split this code

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass


class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        A.foo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    aa = A()
    bb = B(aa)
```

in two separated files

**classA.py**

```
from classB import B


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass
```

and **classB.py**

```
from classA import A


class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        A.foo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    aa = A()
    bb = B(aa)
```

But this leads to an ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'A' from partially initialized module 'classA' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

If one instead uses

**classA.py**

```
import classB


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = classB.B(self)

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass
```

and **classB.py**

```
import classA


class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        classA.A.foo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    aa = classA.A()
    bb = B(aa)
```

everything is fine. But this second version needs some significant changes to the code. Is there a way to split the content of two python classes referring to each other into two files, without the need to rename the methods?

Comment: Circular imports must be done by importing the whole module.  Trying to use `from module import X` should be avoided in these cases.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/2532408 has a pretty good explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the link. That explains it really well. If you want, you can put this comment as an answer an I will accept it.

Comment: I think technically folks would consider this a duplicate, but I appreciate it.